# Low-quality vector scaling using Viewbox and Canvas - How to improve the quality?

Tags: wpf, vector, progress-bar, scale, viewbox

I have designed a **full-vector** Progressbar in a **200x200 Viewbox** *as you can see in the image below.* When finished, and I spent lots of time for it, I scale the Viewbox to **50x50** then I saw it low-quality.

```
<Viewbox Width="200" Height="200">
    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200">
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
            </Canvas.Effect>
            <local:Arc .../>
            <local:Arc .../>
        </Canvas>
        <local:Arc .../>
        <local:Arc .../>
        <local:Arc .../>
        <local:Arc .../>
        <TextBlock .../>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

[<<< **See this image** >>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMAmz.png)

I thought that maybe it is usual, but when Photoshop scaled it to 25% with Bilinear Interpolation *(the simplest interpolation after Nearest Neighborhood)*, I understand that it is WPF goofs!

Is there a way to scale **vector designs** with **good quality** using Viewbox?

I know that ***RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"*** and ***UseLayoutRounding="True"*** can improve image quality but not for vectors.

I wish there would be something like this: ***RenderOptions.VectorScalingMode="HighQuality"***

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a big difference. Have you tried [`UseLayoutRounding`](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/12/20/454-uselayoutrounding-vs-snapstodevicepixels/) ?

Comment: I have tried both SnapsToDevicePixels and UseLayoutRouting and got no good result.

Comment: Hey I have searched a lot but nothing found, Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly improve the rendering quality of vector images (at least for low resolutions) by using the following settings:

```
<Style.Setters>
 <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality" />
 <Setter Property="RenderOptions.EdgeMode" Value="Aliased" />
 <Setter Property="CacheMode">
  <Setter.Value>
   <BitmapCache SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderAtScale="2" />
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style.Setters>
```